# BoundedDiagram Error

Tags: computational-geometry

Although `BoundedDiagram` function worked well for a small data set, I got errors in a specific case that I cannot explain. I am sorry I am pasting here a large list but you could not verify it otherwise:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];

data2D = {{0., 0.1846}, {-0.1846, 0.}, {0., -0.1846}, {0.1846, 0.}, {0.4189,0.2418}, 
          {0.2418, 0.4189}, {0., 0.4837}, {-0.2418, 0.4189}, {-0.4189, 0.2418}, 
          {-0.4837, 0.},{-0.4189, -0.2418}, {-0.2418, -0.4189}, {0., -0.4837},
          {0.2418, -0.4189}, {0.4189, -0.2418}, {0.4837, 0.}, {0.8455, 0.}, 
          {0.8041, 0.2613}, {0.684, 0.497}, {0.497, 0.684}, {0.2613, 0.8041},
          {0., 0.8455}, {-0.2613, 0.8041}, {-0.497, 0.684}, {-0.684, 0.497},
          {-0.8041, 0.2613}, {-0.8455, 0.}, {-0.8041, -0.2613}, {-0.684, -0.497}, 
          {-0.497, -0.684}, {-0.2613, -0.8041}, {0., -0.8455}, {0.2613, -0.8041}, 
          {0.497, -0.684}, {0.684, -0.497}, {0.8041, -0.2613}, {1.2923, 0.}, 
          {1.2599, 0.2876}, {1.1643, 0.5607}, {1.0103, 0.8057}, {0.8057, 1.0103},
          {0.5607, 1.1643}, {0.2876, 1.2599}, {0., 1.2923}, {-0.2876, 1.2599}, 
          {-0.5607, 1.1643}, {-0.8057, 1.0103}, {-1.0103, 0.8057}, {-1.1643, 0.5607},
          {-1.2599, 0.2876}, {-1.2923, 0.}, {-1.2599, -0.2876}, {-1.1643, -0.5607}, 
          {-1.0103, -0.8057}, {-0.8057, -1.0103}, {-0.5607, -1.1643}, {-0.2876, -1.2599}, 
          {0., -1.2923}, {0.2876, -1.2599}, {0.5607, -1.1643}, {0.8057, -1.0103}, 
          {1.0103, -0.8057}, {1.1643, -0.5607}, {1.2599, -0.2876}};
```

You can see in

```
ListPlot[data2D, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

and in

```
DiagramPlot[data2D]
```

that the `Voronoi` Areas appear clear.

But when using

```
BoundedDiagram[{{-4, -4}, {4, -4}, {4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, data2D]
```

I get errors like :

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
>
> BoundedDiagram::nobd: Bounded diagram failed.

If I limit the data set I get correct results (but not always):

```
BoundedDiagram[{{-4, -4}, {4, -4}, {4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, data2D[[1 ;; 10]]]
```

Notice that `VoronoiDiagram[data2D]` produces the correct `Voronoi` data.

Can anybody explain why this is happening or is it a *Mathematica* bug ?

**Solution**

Following Belisarius' advice, I am rolling my own algorithm. Actually I used `VoronoiDiagram` function (why invent the wheel?). I used a circular bound (of radius 1.5) that seems more appropriate for my application.

```
v = VoronoiDiagram[data2D];

intersection[ray_, radius_] :=
  Module[{start = ray[[1]], end = ray[[2]], sx, sy, ex, ey, l},
    {sx, sy} = start; {ex, ey} = end;
    l = 
      (sx*ex + sy*ey + Sqrt[(sx*ex + sy*ey)^2 - (ex^2 + ey^2) (sx^2 + sy^2 - radius^2)])/
        (ex^2 + ey^2);
    start + l*(end - start)];

{vorvert, vorval} =
  {Table[
     If[Head[v[[1, i]]] === Ray, 
       intersection[v[[1, i]], radius = 1.5], 
       v[[1, i]]], 
     {i, 1, Length[v[[1]]]}],
   v[[2]]};

DiagramPlot[data2D, vorvert, vorval]
```

[image]

I welcome any improvement - addition.

Comment: I am thinking about generalizing for arbitrary boundary shape. This is a challenge!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the high symmetry of the point set results in an ill-conditioned matrix. You can see it from:

```
BoundedDiagram[1.5 {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}},  Union@data2D]
```

> RowReduce::luc: Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix {{0.,-3.,4.5},{1.11022*10^-16,-1.11022*10^-16,0.}} may contain significant numerical errors. >>

So, let's perturb the points slightly:

```
noise[x_] := x + RandomReal[{0, 10^-4}, 2]
data2DD = noise /@ data2D;
{diagvert1, diagval1} = BoundedDiagram[1.5 {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Union@data2DD];
DiagramPlot[data2DD, diagvert1, diagval1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks @belisarius , the original data set was rounded using `Round[data2D,0.0001]` but the symmetry remained. I see a perturbation can produce the Voronoi vertices , edges and areas but they are still an approximation. In problems where accuracy matters a lot someone cannot afford a close solution. Also are you sure perturbating will always work ? I am taking N-integrals in the Voronoi areas to calculate SER (Symbol Error Rate) in telecommunication systems for very low Noise - so perturbation interferes greatly in my solutions. Thus i cannot adapt the above tweak.

Comment: @tchronis then I think you'll have to roll your own algorithm paying particular attention to numerical details.

Comment: @tchronis But if the figure isn't going to change you could pick the polygons by hand once ... just a silly idea.

Comment: Picking by hand is not my favorite :-)

Comment: @tchronis Perhaps you misunderstood me. What I had in mind is the following: 1) Calculate your original bounded diagram 2) If it is ill conditioned, perturb the points and recalculate 3) Keep the polygon edges list , and apply to your original point set 4) Verify that this is a valid bounded diagram for the original point set. You'll find the fourth step is usually unnecessary if the perturbations are small enough (smaller than your `Round[]`)

Comment: thanks, you have a point but again the constellation (this is the official name of the points set) changes constantly (sub-rotations - exploiting symmetries) going towards an equilibrium point using optimization techniques. So my patch above gave the solution i need. I will maybe send a letter to Wolfram about this issue - you think i should ?

Comment: @tchronis Don't really know. `Combinatorica` is being incrementally replaced by core functionality